# Inside the Angular component, how do I create a custom stamp using the Grapecity GcPdfViewer?

Tags: angular, pdf, stamp, grapecity

When the User opens a Pdf inside the GcPdfViewer, they need to stamp the Pdf with an image, the image filepath will be in the src/assets folder, but the example from this web page does not work?  Can someone provide me with a working example?

There error i'm getting is "(TS) Type is missing properties.

https://www.grapecity.com/documents-api-pdfviewer/demos/editor-features/annotation-editor/stamp-annotations/client-predefined-stamps/purejs

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The following syntax fixed the errors ... 

  this.viewer = new GcPdfViewer("#viewer", {
            workerSrc: "//node_modules/@grapecity/gcpdfviewer/gcpdfviewer.worker.js",
            //supportApi: {
            //    apiUrl: "api/pdf-viewer",
            //    token: "support-api-demo",
            //    webSocketUrl: false
            //},
            stamp: {
                stampCategories: [
                    {
                        name: 'Custom Stamps',
                        stampImageUrls: [
                            '/path/to/your/custom/stamp1.png',
                            '/path/to/your/custom/stamp2.png',
                            '/path/to/your/custom/stamp3.png',
                            // Add more custom stamp image URLs as needed
                        ],
                        id: '1234',
                        stampImages: [],
                        isDynamic: true,
                        dpi: 90
                    },
                ]
            }
        });
```